# Weighted binomial confidence interval in Stata

Tags: stata, survey, intervals

I am trying to compute a binomial confidence interval for a dummy variable after specifying the survey design in Stata with the `svyset` command but I get the following error: *ci is not supported by svy with vce(linearized)*

```
svyset [pweight=My_weight]
svy: ci Variable, binomial
```

I have also tried the following code:

```
ci Variable [pweight=My_weight], binomial
```

But got the error: *pweight not allowed*

Answer (score 0):

Binomial confidence intervals are calculated as proportions in Stata 14 (Stata 13 uses binomial). This makes sense because the mean of a dummy variable is the proportion of 1's. Look at the help file here: http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?ci

So you likely want a command like:

```
ci proportions Variable [pweight=My_weight]
```

From the help file, it looks like only fweights may be allowed here.

Originally I thought that a better way might be to grab your CI from the means output.  Here is an example modified from the svy help file.

```
  webuse nhanes2f
  svyset psuid [pweight=finalwgt]   
  svy: mean sex
```

But OP is right, this doesn't adjust for the binomial distribution.

Comment: The mean command does not take into account the binomial distribution of my variable and does not allow me to compute alternative methods for binomial confidence intervals such as wald, wilson or aggresti.